# How to move SVG / polyline

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Right now the polyline/chevron is to the right of the words. How do I make it so that it is at the beginning of each accordion instead. Thank you. (I’m talking about the chevron I want it at the beginning)

Here is the code. Please let me know how to move the polyline! I would like it at the beginning of the accordion headers instead.

I’m not sure what could work

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  font: 100%/1.4 Roboto, sans-serif;
  /*padding: 2em;*/
  color: white;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}


/* accordion component*
*/

.V-accordion {
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.V-accordion+.V-accordion {
  border-top: ;
}

.V-accordion_trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.7rem 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.V-accordion_trigger:hover {
  color: gold/*#477dca*/
  ;
}

.V-accordion_trigger-icon {
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.V-accordion_trigger-icon.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.V-accordion_body {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background: /*#f1f1f1*/
  ;
}

.accordion-enter-active {
  animation: accordion 0.5s forwards;
}

.accordion-leave-active {
  animation: accordion 0.2s 0.2s reverse;
}

@-moz-keyframes accordion {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordion {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes accordion {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes accordion {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.1"></script>

<div id="app">
  <accordion title="FAQ title 1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea enim aliquid itaque esse dolorum aperiam, rerum ab possimus voluptatibus modi nobis, maiores quisquam ut sint impedit dignissimos assumenda tempora quam.</p>
  </accordion>
  <accordion title="FAQ title 2">
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</li>
    </ol>
  </accordion>
  <accordion title="FAQ title 3">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis explicabo porro, voluptatum laborum cumque molestiae quibusdam accusamus sed, quam sint ducimus libero distinctio? Dolore laborum, quos dolorem recusandae deleniti quasi.</p>
  </accordion>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('accordion', {
    props: ['title'],
    template: `
<div class="V-accordion">
<div class="V-accordion_trigger" @click="open = !open">
{{ title }}
<svg class="V-accordion_trigger-icon" :class="{open:open}" width="40" height="12">
<polyline points="12,10 20,2 28,10" stroke="gold" stroke-width="3" fill="none"></polyline>
</svg>
</div>
<transition :name="animation">
<div class="V-accordion_body" v-show="open">
<slot></slot>
</div>
</transition>
</div>
`,
    props: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        default: 'FAQ'
      },
      animation: {
        type: String,
        default: 'accordion'
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        open: false
      }
    }
  });

  const vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {},
    computed: {},
    methods: {},
    mounted() {}
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just change the order of your `{{ title }}` placeholder and place it after the `<svg>` element in your template

Answer (score -2):

The key changes are:

Added display: flex; align-items: center; to .V-accordion_trigger to make the title and polyline appear on the same line and be centered vertically.
Removed the margin-right: 1.5rem; from .V-accordion_trigger since it's not needed anymore.
Added `margin

Comment: This does not really look like an answer here but more a comment as it currently stands.  Consider taking the ORIGINAL question snippet and putting that IN your answer with the actual changes in place.